# Django's RSS framework having a AmbiguousTimeError:

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I am on an old system using Django 1.8 and pytz 2013.9.

We're using RSS and stumbled on a `AmbiguousTimeError` because of the following date: `2022-11-06 01:55:41.107437`.

It **is** an ambiguous time and turns out to haven at `django.utils.timezone.make_aware`:

```
timezone.localize(value, is_dst=None)
```

Since it's an ambiguous time and the source code is explicitly passing no DST, it can't figure out the date (shouldn't the framework figure out whether DST is applied or not through the timezone object?)

This `make_aware` function is, in turn, also called from Django's RSS framework in `django.contrib.syndication.Feed.get_feed`.

The timezone is:

`<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>`

How can I deal with this? The issue lies at the source code.

The problematic element itself is one of the event's updated attribute:

I tried upgrading the package and it doesn't help. I am not able to upgrade Django (large upgrade process pending).

You can test it yourself:

```
import pytz
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-11-06 01:55:41.107437', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
tz.localize(dt, is_dst=None)
```